# how to use value of jquery variable in phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, jquery

I want to use variable in phtml file which is in jquery. I want to use this abc variable in phtml file. How to use it?

```
var abc = $('#limiter option:selected').val();
```

Comment: What do you want?

Comment: I want to get product_list_limit value.

Comment: You already have the value inside `abc`. right?. Now what?

Comment: If you want to know how to use jQuery in magento2 then ask a question like that. Your question is too confusing.

Comment: Now i want to use this value in phtml code... For ex. :- product_page_limit is 9...this value also get in abc variable.. but how to use this value in phtml code?

Comment: It just simple ... that i want to use value of abc variable in phtml file... what confusion you have ?

Comment: You can assign the value to any field. `jQuery('#any-field-id').val(abc);`

Comment: You cannot use js variable in PHP context. a possible workaround would be to send an ajax request to the server. But I have a feeling that this is not what you want. Maybe you should explain the problem and not the solution you tried. Maybe there is a nice way of doing it.

Comment: ok. I got answer...thanks Kingshuk Deb & Marius

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what you wan that variable but you can get value in phtml by simply adding this code

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
 var abc = $('#limiter option:selected').val();
});

</script>
```

here is alternative solution you can define it top on phtml and use in phtml file anywhere

```
<script>
 var abc=document.getElementById("limiter").value
</script>
```

Now you can use it anywhere in phtml file.

Comment: yes. but how to use "abc" value in phtml file... ? I want to get product_page_limit value.....

Comment: Do you have any idea ..? How to get product page limit value which is selected.

Comment: @RohanHapani this code doing the same thing getting the selected limit

Comment: Yes..I know ..this give me perfect ans.
But i want to use that value in whole phtml file...how to use it? @QaisarSatti

Comment: @RohanHapani added the solution with **javascript**.